# Inverse of a predictor in a linear model - R

Tags: r, analytics, linear-regression

I have this linear model in r:

```
a<-lm(NA. ~ PC +SPCI,data=DSET)
```

Now, what I want to run is a linear model with the inverse of SPCI, which is (1/SCPCI).

I guessed that the sintaxis was : `a<-lm(NA. ~ PC +(1/SPCI),data=DSET)`.
But it doesn`t make sense for that code because (1/SPCI) is completely ignored , it's just adding 0.

So, What should I do to run the inverse of a predictor in a linear model in R.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you need to to use the notation of `I` in your formula. See `?formula` for details.

From help of `formula`:
*the function I() can be used to bracket those portions of a model formula where the operators are used in their arithmetic sense. For example, in the formula y ~ a + I(b+c), the term b+c is to be interpreted as the sum of b and c*

#### Example:

```
a<-lm(NA. ~ PC + I(1/SPCI), data=DSET)
```